# How to set background image for body tag using css?

Tags: css, image, background

This is my css...

```
   body{    
   background: url(<?php echo base_url()."images/1.jpg";?>) no-repeat center
   center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;

  -webkit-background-size: cover;

  -o-background-size: cover;
   height: 100%;

   position:absolute; 
   width:100%;
 }
```

I want to set image as full background fit to screen dimensions. Now image displaying as full background but some lower portion of image is not displaying.
So what will be the solution??

Comment: set background-size:100% 100% instead of cover

Comment: Please post this comment as answer..It worked..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `background-size` to `100% 100%` to 'stretch' the image instead.

Note. [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) states that prefixes aren't needed for background-size properties.

```css
 body {
   background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300) no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: hello , it's not working for chrome, working only for firefox

Comment: @KedarB: which version of chrome? (I'm on latest and it's fine?)

Comment: 42.0.2311.11 dev-m (64-bit) and it says it's upto date

Comment: @KedarB: This should work fine. Could you possibly post a fiddle that reproduces the issue for you? As I have tested on chrome.

Comment: In chrome when I inspect element, it shows cross on bacground-size:100%100% property ,..you know what I mean..cross means that horizontal line on property

Comment: @KedarB You are using a developer version, that might be creating a problem. Because here on Chrome 40, it works just fine.

Comment: How Do I change that version??

Comment: Ok..understand I need to change my chrome version from dev to stable by installing another.

Comment: @KedarB Its working fine in Canary too. I think you'll have to uninstall the dev version in order to install the stable version. If you want bleeding edge features, try GC Canary, and it can be installed parallel to your current GC  too!

Comment: Ok..I understand..I will try that.

Comment: @KedarB: Did you get sorted?

Comment: No ..But I know what is the exact problem..So it's not my fault..So I have to change chrome from dev version to stable version.